# Using sed to replace text within a java properties file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a java properties file that looks like the following:

```
SiteUrlEndpoint=google.com/mySite
```

I want to use sed -i to inline replace the url but keep the context path that comes out of it. So for example if I wanted to change the properties file above to use amazon.com then the result would look like:

```
SiteUrlEndpoint=amazon.com/mySite
```

I am having trouble with sed to only replace the url and keeping the context path when replacing it inline.

My attempt:

```
sed -i 's:^[ \t]*siteUrlEndpoint[ \t]*=\([ \t]*.*\)[/]*$:siteUrlEndpoint = 'amazon.com':' file
```

Comment: What did your troublesome sed try look like?

Comment: The regexp in your script starts with a lower case `s` (`site...`) but the text you're trying to match starts with an upper case `S` (`Site...`). That would cause your script to fail no matter what else you did with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with two *backreferences*, e.g.

```
sed -i.bak 's|^\(SiteUrlEndpoint=\).*/\(.*\)|\1amazon.com/\2|' file
```

**note:** the match of text up to `/` is **greedy**. If you have multiple parts of the path following the domain, you probably want to preserve all path components. To make it **non-greedy**, you could use the following instead

```
sed -i.bak 's|^\(SiteUrlEndpoint=\)[^/]*/\(.*\)|\1amazon.com/\2|' file
```

(you can add `i.bak` to create a backup of the original in `file.bak`)

To accomplish the same thing, you can match `SiteUrlEndpoint=` at the beginning of the line first, and then use a single backreference for the change, e.g.

```
sed -i.bak '/^SiteUrlEndpoint=/s|=[^/]*\(/.*\)|=amazon.com\1|' file
```

For example, given a file `sites` containing:

```
$ cat sites
SiteUrlEndpoint=google.com/path/to/mySite
SiteUrlSomeOther=google.com/mySite
```

You can change `google.com` to `amazon.com` with (using non-greedy form of first example):

```
$ sed -i 's|^\(SiteUrlEndpoint=\)[^/]*/\(.*\)|\1amazon.com/\2|' sites
```

Confirming:

```
$ cat sites
SiteUrlEndpoint=amazon.com/path/to/mySite
SiteUrlSomeOther=google.com/mySite
```

and

```
$ cat sites.bak
SiteUrlEndpoint=google.com/path/to/mySite
SiteUrlSomeOther=google.com/mySite
```

***Explanation*** **(first form)**

1. `sed -i.bak 's|^\(SiteUrlEndpoint=\)` - locate & save
   `SiteUrlEndpoint=`
2. `[^/]*/` - match any folowing characters up to first `/` (non-greedy -
   adjust as needed)
3. `\(.*\)` - match and save anything following `/`
4. `|\1amazon.com/\2|'` - **full replacement** (explanation below)
5. `\1` - first back-reference containing `SiteUrlEndpoint=`
6. `amazon.com` - self-explanatory
7. `/\2` - the `'/'` second back-reference of everything that followed.

Look over all the solutions and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Wouldn't this replace anything that has any `=` sign and a `/` in there with amazon? `myvar = 4/6` would be replaced with `myvar = amazon.com/6`

Comment: Yes, I'll drop a specific `:)`

Comment: Plus, I don't know why you wrap the `/` in `[/]` -- I mean if you only have a single character to choose from, why tell it to chose at all?

Comment: It's wrapped to prevent interpretation as a *search delimiter* (which we should probably chose as `|` or something different anyway)

Comment: Thanks this really helped! One question I have is what if I wanted to replace amazon.com with a variable? I tried to include the variable in place of where amazon.com goes but when testing it out sed just inline-replaced the text with the literal name of the variable and not what was assigned to it.

Comment: If you are using a variable, it would be `sed -i 's|^\(SiteUrlEndpoint=\)[^/]*/\(.*\)|\1'"$varname"'/\2|' file`  (without the stupid `&#47` the markdown is doing that on its own) It's `single-quote double-quote${var}double-quote single-quote`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are hard, especially with complex regular expressions and/or large input files where unexpected changes are to be avoided.

Therefore I strongly recommend using `sed -i.bak` to keep a backup of the original file to then run a `diff` on both of them to see what changed.

Assuming that

1. You only want to change things after the tag `siteUrlEndpoint` (case insensitive)
2. You want to change the URL to `amazon.com` while leaving the path intact

I came up with this solution:

```
sed -i.bak 's;^\([ \t]*siteurlendpoint[ \t]*=[ \t]*\)[^/]*\(.*\);\1amazon.com\2;Ig' infile
```

I used a semicolon instead of your colon, that's just my preference when I don't want to use `/` ;)

Then I wrapped both the leading white spaces and `siteurlendpoint` as well as everything from the first `/` onwards into brackets `\( \)` so that I can take them again in the replacement with `\1` and `\2`. That way I keep the indentation and the capitalisation of `SiteUrlEndpoint` intact.

For the search options I added an `I` to the `g` to make the search case insensitive. I am not sure how standard this option is, you might have to see whether your `sed` understands it.

The actual part that I want to replace I have just any character not including the next `/`: `[^/]*`

As for your line:

1. Your search term only searches for `siteUrlEndpoint` with lower case s. Since in your examples you wrote it with capital S, it wouldn't have triggered.
2. The final `[/]*$` doesn't make any sense at all. "This line can end in zero or more of any of these caracters: `/`."
3. You precede this `[/]*$` with `.*` which means: zero or more of any character at all.
4. The single quotes around `'amazon.com'` might interfere with the single quotes around the whole search/replace term. It seems to work, but it is sloppy, and will fail if there are ever any spaces in there. It doesn't seem to serve any purpose anyway (except if you want to replace `amazon.com` with some environment variable like `$NEWSITE`) so I don't know why you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a backreference to the part just before the domain - then match and replace the domain - you can add the -i option after verifying the output of the sed command

```
url=amazon.com
sed -r 's/\b(SiteUrlEndpoint\s*=\s*)[^/]+/\1'$url'/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
$ sed -E 's/(SiteUrlEndpoint=)[^.]+/\1amazon/' file
SiteUrlEndpoint=amazon.com/mySite
```